# Is it possibel to share SOLR index "term dictionaries" across fields

Tags: solr, lucene, inverted-index

SOLR (Lucene) indices, like all *inverted indices*, use a *term dictionary* to assign an index to each term. Each field in the index generates its own term dictionary (which can be inspected in the SOLR admin tool).

I have a very large SOLR index, where each document has very many textual fields. All fields contain english text following a similar distribution.

In my case this is very wasteful: it maintains many very large term dictionaries (in memory) which are almost all the same... as the number of (different) terms in the documents grows these dictionaries grow very large.

I cannot combine all fields into a single search field because I need to run queries restricted over specific fields.

Is there a way to tell SOLR to **use the same term dictionary** for several fields?

(Afterthought: but perhaps if terms follow a zipfian distribution, the ammount of sharing between fields won't be significant anyway as many terms will appear only once and hence only in one dict?)